# How to setup wxPython/robot framework RIDE on MAC?the wxPython did not work after run ride.py(on MAC OS)

Tags: python, macos, wxpython, robotframework

I try to install Robot Framework RIDE to MAC(version 10.9.5) today.

1. python version is 2.7.9(is default version in MAC)
2. installed wxPython 2.8.12.1, install success.
3. install Robot Framework(robotframework-ride-1.1) success.

when I try to open graphic tool RIDE and run ride.py.

I got return:

> wxPython not found. You need to install wxPython 2.8 or 2.9 toolkit
>   with unicode support to run RIDE. See http://wxpython.org for more
>   information.

Actually, I have installed wxPython 2.8.12.1, and when I try to run "import wx" in python env, I can got wxPython information return.

Anyone know how should I open graphic tool RIDE? Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to install software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I re setup os for MAC, I know this is not good solution for this issue. List all detail steps below：

1. Python 2.7.5(this is best choose, or you can setup version 2.7.x)
2. wxPython 2.8.12.1(must need unicode version      http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/2.8.12.1/)
3. robot framework (lastest version: )
4. robot framework RIDE (BETTER version 1.2.3 )
5. run ride.py
   will got error:
   “python should be executed in 32-bit mode to support wxPython on mac. Check BUILD.rest for details"
   so python just support 32bit, run:
   "defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Prefer-32-Bit -bool yes”
6. Try again: ride.py
   RIDE should be launched.

Answer (score 0):

On some Mac OS X (El Capitan, Yosemite) wxPython 2.8 just doesn't work. You need to install wxPython 3.0. For exaple from here:

But as RobotFramework-Ride 1.5 doesn't support wxPython 3.0 yet, you'll need to install RobotFramework-Ride 2.0 beta that is avaliable only by easy_install:

```
    easy_install robotframework-ride
```

That works on my Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked like a charm for me:

I went to this directory: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/robotframework_ride-2.0a1-py2.7.egg/robotide`

and then ran `arch -i386 python __init__.py`,

It launched RIDE editor!